# Phonegap loadUrl try/catch and retry

Tags: android, cordova

I want to be able to load a local default html page when a user has no internet connection (or the server does not response) and then load the external web site when they do. I am thinking to use try/catch block for this, when the error occurs, then load a local page, and user click retry button on it to try again. I am coding for Android 3.2 platform.

My question is how to complete the following code? Any sample?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try
    {
        super.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // how to catch the error, then show the local page to retry.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At least for the no connectivity error / unknown connectivity error, you can do this by using the Phonegap `Connection` class. You can try to check the state of the connection type, then do appropriate action based on that.

This is the way you do it using the Phonegap Cordova javascript library: 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/phonegap_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

You need to figure the equivalent way to do it in Eclipse (using Java codes). A framework like Phonegap should have the Java API for that. Check out the Javadocs and documentation of PhoneGap.